# Switch between pages every few minutes

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have developed 3 `.asp` pages for a project I have been working on. Is it possible to add code to these pages that automatically rotates them among themselves?

Example:

> I open `page1.asp` --> (5 minutes later some script runs) --> and `page2.asp`
>   opens automatically --> (A further 5 minutes later, the script runs
>   again) --> And `page3.asp` is now displayed. [All of this in the same tab]

I have to display graphs to a department on performance. Page one will be daily performance, page 2 will be weekly, and page 3 will be monthly.

I need these to rotate between themselves every so often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `refresh <meta>` in each page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="yourtimeinseconds;url=yourpage" />
```

You could add one of this to each of the pages with link to the next page, like:

**Page1:**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300;url=page2.asp" />
```

**Page2:**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300;url=page3.asp" />
```

**Page3:**

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300;url=page1.asp" />
```

This should do the trick. No script needed.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd second this one over the other solutions since it works even with scripting disabled. At our company, some of the remote access technologies have caused odd problems with scripting, leading us to prefer options like this.

Comment: Awesome :) Thank you so much... This does exactly what I need. 

On a side note though - I was already using a meta refresh on my pages to refresh the data every so often. is it possible to still use both on the same page? (Not a train smash if not, as I will just use your one then)

Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using some javascript carousel.
Could this help you? :
http://kreaturamedia.com/layerslider-responsive-jquery-slider-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>    
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.location.href = "/page2/"
    },60000);
</script>
```

The 60000 represents the number of milliseconds in 5 minutes.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LZqhZ/)